# Dynamically remove a string that follows a JSON embedded in HTML code, using Python?

Tags: python, html, json

i'm currently trying to parse and extract a JSON from a page using BeautifulSoup.

So far, it goes as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re


url = 'www.html_code_url'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for script in soup.findAll('script'):
    if 'required_json_content'in script.get_text():
        json = script.get_text.replace('unnecessary_stuff','')
```

I also replace other tags that come along when I extract the JSON.

However, there is a portion of the text which I can't really remove. It goes something like this, right after the JSON:

```
something.push({"key1" : "field1","dict1" : [{"Id": 12479895,"randomnumber" :  1325757 ,"WebTree":{"options":[]}}]})
```

Is there a way to remove this 100 percent of the time?

Comment: Remove that text from what?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract the data you need - instead of replacing the data you don't need?